# Jquery .trigger('stop') method for .draggable

Tags: jquery, event-handling, draggable

```
$('#element').draggable ({
    stop: function () {
        alert ('stopped');
        //do some action here
    }
}).trigger('stop');
```

nothing happens, thought `#element` is draggable now and event does execute after drag is complete. I tried `.triggerHandle` as well as `'dragstop'` as eventtype, no luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this to trigger it instead:

```
.trigger('dragstop')
```

If you want it to behave *completely* as a normal event, use .bind('dragstop', function) to attach it as well, the start option behaves slightly differently.

Comment: @selytch - did you try using .bind()? The callback is treated a bit different than a straight bind being called is here.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I did not realize .bind works differently. Is this documented? (probably yes...)

Comment: @selytch - nope, not well documented at all, just something you notice when loooking at the jQuery UI source, I agree it needs to be noted better somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but now it is possible to trigger the actual drag event of jquery ui instead of the dragstart and dragstop by using the [jQuery simulate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/9e8e339648901899827a58e5bf919f7dda03b88e/tests/jquery.simulate.js).

Here is the code I used because I needed access to the snapping elements of my resizable object (data only accesible on drag stop)

```
$(this).resizable({
    handles: 'e',
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        var resizable = ui.element;             
        resizable.simulate("mousedown", {clientX: e.clientX, clientY: e.clientY});
        resizable.simulate("mousemove", {clientX: e.clientX + 10, clientY: e.clientY + 10});
        resizable.simulate("mouseup", {clientX: e.clientX, clientY: e.clientY});
    }
});
```